# Sort ArrayList by search keyword

Tags: android, sorting, collections

I have an ArrayList with This values

```
"Babel"
"Isabelle"
"Elon"
"Eloise"
```

I'm typing "el" on the search, I sort the list and I would like to have this result

```
"Eloise"
"Elon"
"Babel"
"Isabelle"
```

Because `"Eloise"` start with my search `"el"` like `"Elon"` and then `"Babel"` because alphabetically is before `"Isabelle"`

I don't know how to sort by the firsts chars of the array I try to substring names

```
  users.sort((o1, o2) -> {
                         String name1 = o1.getNickname();
                         String name2 = o2.getNickname();
                         if (o1.getNickname().length() >= finalS.length()) {
                               name1 = o1.getNickname().substring(0, finalS.length());
                         }
                         if (o2.getNickname().length() >= finalS.length()) {
                               name2 = o2.getNickname().substring(0, finalS.length());
                         }
                         return name1.compareTo(name2);
                        });
```

But this  `return name1.compareTo(name2);` compare the cutted String and order alphabetical.
I try to add this below the substring

```
   if (name1.contains(finalS)) return 1;
```

or

```
    if (name2.contains(finalS)) return 1;
```

nothing work `Babel` is always at the first position

Comment: and what it it doesn't contains your search ? remeber! it's sort! not filter

Comment: @Selvin I just remove it from the list

Comment: again, sort cannot remove

Comment: @Selvin yes I know I'm doing it before the sort

Comment: The you have 4 choices inside sort ... 1. both starts with search - return compare
2.(3.) only first(second) starts with search - return 1 (-1)  4. non starts from search - return compare ... it's not a rocket science ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases, the factory methods in the `Comparator` interface are suitable and allow to reduce the redundancy of applying operations to both arguments of the comparator.

Since your input is `"el"` but the names start with an uppercase letter, you want a case insensitive partial matching, followed by sorting by the strings’ natural order.

```java
List<String> users = Arrays.asList("Babel", "Isabelle", "Elon", "Eloise");
String finalS = "el";

users.sort(Comparator.comparing(
    (String u) -> !finalS.regionMatches(true, 0, u, 0, finalS.length()))
    .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));

users.forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
Eloise
Elon
Babel
Isabelle
```

Since apparently there’s a class `User` whose `Nickname` property you want to compare, the complete sorting code would look like

```java
users.sort(Comparator.comparing(User::getNickname, Comparator.comparing(
    (String u) -> !finalS.regionMatches(true, 0, u, 0, finalS.length()))
    .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Comparator should look kind of like this:
Sorts those which start with your search first, then those which only contain them. But the best way for searching would be to use diff-match-patch (https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch).

```java
 public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
    String search = YOUR_SEARCH.toLowerCase();
    String name1 = o1.getNickname().toLowerCase();
    String name2 = o2.getNickname().toLowerCase();

    int i = Boolean.compare(name2.startsWith(search), name1.startsWith(search));
    if (i != 0)
      return i;
    i = Boolean.compare(name2.contains(search), name1.contains(search));
    if (i != 0)
      return i;
    return name2.compareTo(name1);
  }
```

Comment: since he already filtering the one which not contains `search` this can be simplified to `int i = Boolean.compare(name2.startsWith(search), name1.startsWith(search)); return i == 0 ? name2.compareTo(name1) : i;` ... but good answer anyway ...